# minItems=1 and "uniqueItems": true for array type property in mongodb @document

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, spring-data

I am using spring data for a REST API. There is a document with following properties

```
"properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Object id from the database"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "English User name"
    },
    "continents": {
      "type": "array",
      "description": "Continents the User exist in",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": { "type": "string" },
      "uniqueItems": true
    }
  }
```

For these properties I am writing a java persistent class as below

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String name;
// what annotation I should I apply here for constraints minItems=1 and "uniqueItems": true ?

    private String[] continents;
    // getter and setters   
}
```

I want to support "minItems": 1, "uniqueItems": true for continents. Can anyone please help me how to do it in User.java?

Comment: What do you mean "support"?

Comment: I mean any annotation is available to apply constraints  "minItems": 1, "uniqueItems": true on continents.

Comment: By "apply constraints", do you mean that you are wanting to require those properties to be present?

Comment: minItems": 1, "uniqueItems": true --> are not properties, these are constraints on Field "continents" ( a column of a record of User ). Basically "continents" should be a String array which I have achieved by declaration "private String[] continents; " but it has to meet two more criteria "minItems": 1, "uniqueItems": true. This I want to be done through any annotation ( if available )

Comment: So many questions like this unanswered. Bad mongo coverage on SO. Shame.